# Git plugin RAD not working

Tags: git, plugins, rad

I have RAD 8.5.5.2 and was trying to install Git using http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates site. I am getting the following error can someone please help.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider 4.0.1.201506240215-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 4.0.1.201506240215-r)
  Missing requirement: Eclipse Git Team Provider 4.0.1.201506240215-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 4.0.1.201506240215-r) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

Screen shot attached with the selection I made to install.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your RAD 8.5.5.2 is based on Eclipse 3.6 (Juno).

Check the reference table "What versions of Eclipse does EGit target?" in the [EGit FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ).

EGit 2.1 is the latest version supported in Eclipse 3.6; 
try this update site link: http://archive.eclipse.org/egit/updates-2.1

To try to install EGit 3.7.0 or older, you can use this update site link: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-3.7

Comment: with above link it's installing the Git , but it's not showing in git Perspective list, could you please give proper steps how we can see git in RAD